# ggplot fortify ignores order of spatial data

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sp

I am having some trouble with ggplot's fortify. When using Open Streetmap shapefile, fortify is loosing the order of some lines. The order must be correct in the file as qgis and the sp package have no problem with the plots.

### Here is an example with some roads of a German town.

**Qgis:**

[image: qgis image]

Looks good in **sp**:

[image: sp image]

But after using fortify, there are some problems in **ggplot** like the enter/exit of the highway:

[image: ggplot image]

---

### Here is a little example of that highway-part

([data is here](http://www.ahschulz.de/pub/overflow/20151217_fortify/sample_shape.RData))

```
library(ggplot)
library(sp)

plot(sample_shape)
ggplot(data = fortify(sample_shape), aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), size = 0.05) + geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

Again, **sp** looks nice, **ggplot** does not:
[image: sp sample]
[image: ggplot sample]

Any help or hints is/are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ggplot()` you should use `geom_path()` instead of `geom_point()`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
load("sample_shape.RData")
ggplot(data = fortify(sample_shape),
       aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), size = 0.05) +
       geom_path() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: But the roads are lines and not areas (cf. qgis/sp images).

Comment: @ahs85 I just edited the answer. `geom_path()` is better for roads, `geom_polygon()` is good for administrative boundaries.